# Python3 + vagrant ubuntu 16.04 + ssl request = [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, google-api, vagrant, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using on my Mac Vagrant with "bento/ubuntu-16.04" box. I'm trying to use Google Adwords Api via python library but got error `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

I make sample script to check possibility to send requests:

```
import urllib.request

url ="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201609/ManagedCustomerService?wsdl"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read())
```

If I try this request via python3 - I've got `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`.
But if I send request via curl `curl https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201609/ManagedCustomerService?wsdl` - I've got some response( even if it is 500 code) with body.

If I try this sample python script from my host Mac machine - I also receive some text response.
I tried this script from VDS server with ubuntu 16.04 - also worked.

So I assume, problem is possible between Vagrant/Mac.

Maybe you can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It looks like bug in Virtualbox 5.1.8 version. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7946)

So, you can fix it by downgrade Virtualbox to < 5.1.6